# Can't render font in class defined in Stylus with @font-face in Chrome

Tags: css, express, font-face, meanjs, stylus

I have a MEAN application running Angular2 for the frontend part, with Stylus-based CSS definition.

After compilation, resources are on the following tree folder:

- dist
- - backend
- - frontend
- - **resources**
- - - font.woff
- - - font.woff2
- - - general.css (compiled styles, obviously)

general.css is compiled from general.styl, which is

```
@font-face
  font-family: retro-computer
  src: url(font.woff2) format(woff2)
  src: url(font.woff) format(woff)

nav
  border-width: 10px
  border-style: solid
  font-family: retro-computer
```

That seems correct, as the location of the fonts are in the same folder so the relative url is straightforward.

In order to be sure that the fonts are available throughout the server, the static path is defined correctly in app.ts in backend.

```
private config() {
  this.app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "..", "frontend", "views"));
  this.app.set("view engine", "hbs");

  this.app.use("/scripts", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "frontend")));
  this.app.use("/node_modules", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "node_modules"))); 
  this.app.use("/resources/styles", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "resources", "styles"))); //<-- THIS
}
```

So, attempting to get the font from http://localhost:8000/resources/styles/font.woff works fine, the font is downloaded from the browser.

Generated CSS is also perfectly reached from the home page, and the styles are included in the Angular2 app. If I change the background-color of the nav, the border size, etc. from the style, the altered style is shown.

Problem is the font. It is not rendered whatsoever in Chrome (in Windows Edge works fine, still haven't tested in FF). What am I doing wrong? I have tried playing around the path in the stylus file, even directly in generated CSS, but the problem persists.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem. Chrome seems a bit picky regarding quotation marks in css, so using " for the format made the trick.